# Ubuntu 18.04: Steam Proton / Steam Play Games doesnt start

Tags: 18.04, steam

I have installed a few games with platinum level, but the games doesnt launch.

This happens with following games:

command and conquer tiberian wars

command and conquer kanes wrath

ultimate doom

There is no error message or anything like that.

I have installed the nvidia 415.25 driver with vulkan.

Comment: Ultimate doom does start when i install this game on the standard library folder

Comment: Such issues really need to be reported to Steam or the games' developers, as they are all proprietary and you are using them on proprietary drivers. Or at least the Community page on Steam for each game.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a Solution: The Steam Library was installed on a NTFS-Partition.
I moved the Library to a ext4 Partition. Now it works well

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble myself in the past with games running on Proton/Steam Play.

Thus, I recommend you try executing this command :`sudo vkvia`, and then try to launch your games again.

Apparently, some games (even native Vulkan games such as Dota) cannot gain access to the Vulkan libraries directly, and because this command launches a Vulkan installation test, it forces them to load (don't take my word for it, it is only what I *think* happens), and then your games might run fine.